# Find two sequences $(a_n)$ and $(a_n)$ such that lim$(a_n)$ = lim$(b_n)$ = 0, but lim$(a_n)^{(b_n)}$ = 2022

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

This is a problem from my real analysis class. I've tried beginning with guesses for the sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ to obtain an indeterminate form $0^0$ so that I can take the natural log of $(a_n)^{(b_n)}$. Then using log properties, I tried to apply L'Hospital's rule and find the limit. I think this is probably the right approach, but so far my guesses have proved inaccurate (i.e. $(a_n)$ = $\frac{1}{n}$ or $\frac{1}{n^2}$; have also tried playing around with putting 2022 or ln(2022) in both the numerator and denominator of one of the sequences). I've also tried working backwards, i.e. starting with lim($(a_n)^{(b_n)}$) = 2022 to try to find an $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ that work, but neither approach has proved particularly helpful. Hoping for a way to think about this logically to understand the *form* of the desired sequences.

Comment: You're on the right track, but I think you've put the cart before the horse a bit. _Start_ by taking the natural log of the sequence; you'll get $\lim_{n\to\infty}(b_n\ln a_n) = \ln(2022)$. Here we can use a different name for the sequence $\ln a_n$; let's set $c_n=\ln a_n$. Now try and find sequences for $b_n$ and for $c_n$ such that $b_n\to 0$, $c_n\to-\infty$, and that their product goes to $\ln(2022)$ — in fact, you should even be able to have every term equal to that... Once you've done that, you can get $a_n$ back by $a_n=e^{c_n}$.

Comment: Hint: $\frac1n$ was a good idea, just not for $(a_n)$. And remember that negative $b_n$ are necessary (otherwise, $a_n^{b_n} \le 1$.

Comment: Instead of starting with $\lim a_n^{b_n}=2022$ start with $a_n^{b_n}=2022$ for every $n.$

Answer (score 2):

What if you put $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$, and $b_n = -\frac{\ln(2022)}{\ln(n)}$ for all integers $n \ge 2$. Then clearly both $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$ $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n = 0$.

Then also, for each $n$:
$$a_n^{b_n} = \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-\frac{ln(2022)}{\ln(n)}}$$ $$= e^{-\ln(n) \times -\frac{\ln(2022)}{\ln(n)}} = e^{\ln(2022)} = 2022.$$